# Why do we use "vel" in equations - inequalities range of solutions?

Tags: inequality, boolean-algebra

I'd like to ask a very simple question. Why do we use "vel" between the solutions of inequalities?
I mean, to solve
$ \ \ \large x^2-7x \geq 0$ we write $\large x\leq 0 \vee x \geq 7 $. 
Aren't we supposing that there's a possibility to have contemporarely two $x$ values using the logical OR?
Shouldn't we be using the logical XOR (also known as $\bigoplus$)?
$$\large x\leq 0 \ \scriptsize \bigoplus \ \  \large  x \geq 7 $$

$x$ can obviously be only either in one range or the other, why are we considering that it can belong to both?
Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\vee$ means "or".  But (as you noted) it is confusing.  So just write "or" instead.  Even worse is $\oplus$ for exclusive or.  Do not use it in mathematical writing.  In words you can say " ... or ... but not both".  That will make it clear to the reader [the purpose of mathematical writing is to make it clear to the reader].

In this case, $x$ cannot satisfy both.  So you could write "$x \le 0$ or $x \ge 7$ but not both".  Of course this is the same as "$x \le 0$ or $x \ge 7$", so you could write that (as your source did).  If both is impossible, then there is no need to assert "but not both" unless you want to for fun.

Comment: This is also a breakdown of English and mathematical language which you allude to here. In plain English, "or" is often meant as exclusive or, but this is not the case in mathematics. I've seen many a young student get confused by this. That aside, I echo the sentiment of using language rather than symbols anywhere that it brings more clarity. This is a good example of such. Adding the disjunction symbol can only lead to confusion.

Comment: @Cameron Williams This possible confusion is also present in the case of French language and surely as well in Spanish and Italian.

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess that makes sense! I am not fluent enough in other languages to comment on this though 